# Attribute "barLength" has already been defined

Tags: android, material-design

I have just updated Material Design Support Lib to v23.0.1 and now, my code doesn't compile anymore.

```
Attribute "barLength" has already been defined
/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

What should I do?

EDIT:

The 2 libs that gives me the error are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you do not have any attribute named "barLength". In my case a custom ProgressWheel caused the issue, renamed attr name and problem resolved.

Comment: Thanks.I also have barlength for my custom progress wheel.After I rename, problem solved. Thanks

Comment: this was the issue tx

Comment: may be need to check attr.xml, i had the same issue with custom ProgressBar

Comment: How to resolved it in case two libraries have same name for attribute. In my case: andoid data binding library and micro-blink android library https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android library

Answer (score 11):

The `android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse` and `android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored` error is due to you are still using Android Lollipop (API 21) compiler. Change your `compileSdkVersion` to 23.

`Attribute "barLength" has already been defined` error is due to your Gradle version is outdated. Go to `Preference` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`, change `Gradle home` to the latest Gradle version (Mine is `gradle-2.4`)

Remember to change your project `build.gradle` to use the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'
}
```

And also change your `buildToolsVersion` to `22.0.1`.

**Edit:**

I noticed that you're using `ProgressWheel` library, created by Todd Davies. There is a conflict of `declare-styleable`, i.e. the `barLength` dimension. In that case you'll need to import Progress Wheel as a module in Android Studio and change the name of the attribute.

Comment: Gradle 1.4 is not released yet https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Comment: @Ricardo latest version is Gradle 1.4 beta 6, I'm using that one.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I had ProgressWheel in my module - Crazy infuriating that it took so long for me to find the conflict, it didn't tell me where it was originally defined, only where it was defined the second time.

Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update your libraries that use the support library to use the same version as the project's support library

Comment: How can I do that? I think the conflict is with a lib that use : progressWheel : https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel, but I don't know how to modify it as it is included with Gradle

Comment: I think this might not be true. I just checked the library you mentioned and found out it doesn't depend on the support library. anyway, if the problem is with one of the libraries you're using via gradle, you can add the library as a module in Android Studio (or library in case you're using Eclipse) and modify it's dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

buildToolsVersion 21
targetSdkVersion "22.0.1"