# want to add design library in app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add 'design' library in my android app. Simply it added and works perfectly but if i add design library with my app's other library then gradle file gives error.

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/oovoosdk.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
}
```

It gives following error  :

```
Error:(2) Attribute "buttonBarButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/ptiweb/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Please help me to solve this.How could i add "appcompat" or "design" library in this file.

Comment: Seems duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441420/attribute-barlength-has-already-been-defined in other words there is already a attribute defined with the name buttonBarButtonStyle this cannot be so avoid using duplicate attribute names

Comment: make sure that match your minSdkVersion , targetSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion..

Comment: change existing style name before add design support library

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you do not have any `attribute` named `"barLength"`.**

In my case a custom ProgressWheel caused the issue, renamed attr name and problem resolved.

For more refer [Attribute "barLength" has already been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441420/attribute-barlength-has-already-been-defined)

Comment: yes I changed name of attribute then it will successfully run